# Schanuel's Lemma

Tags: exact-sequence, projective-module

I want to prove the following:

> Assume that we have two exact sequences of $R$-modules $$0 \to K \xrightarrow{\psi} P \xrightarrow{\varphi} M \to 0$$ and $$0 \to K' \xrightarrow{\psi'} P' \xrightarrow{\varphi'} M \to 0$$ where $P,P'$ are *projective*, and we want to prove that $$P \oplus K' \cong P' \oplus K.$$

My reasoning:
We have the fiber-product
$$
X := \{(p,p') \;|\; p \in P, p' \in P', \ \text{such that} \ \varphi(p) = \varphi'(p')\}
$$
of $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$.

We look at the sequence
$$
0 \to \operatorname{ker}(\pi) \xrightarrow{\iota} X \xrightarrow{\pi} P \to 0.
$$

where (I believe) $\iota:\operatorname{ker}(\pi) \to X$ is just the injection of elements in $X$ that get sent to $0$ under $\pi$, and $\pi:X \to P$ is the surjection from the fiber-product *onto* $P$. Now, since $\pi$ is the projection, it is surjective, and clearly the injection $\iota$ is injective, hence we get an exact sequence.

Now, since $P$ is a *projective* $R$-module, we have that that every short exact sequence splits, so that the there exists a *section* $h:P \to X$ so that $h(P) \cong P$ and we have
$$
X \cong \operatorname{ker}(\pi) \oplus h(P) \cong \operatorname{ker}(\pi) \oplus P.
$$

Now, we note that $\pi:X \twoheadrightarrow P$ must be defined explicitly (I think) by $(p,p') \longmapsto p$ so that
$$
\operatorname{ker}(\pi) = \{(0,p')\;|\; p' \in P' \ \text{such that} \ \varphi(0) = \varphi'(p')\}
$$
hence if $(0,p') \in \operatorname{ker}(\pi) \implies \varphi'(p') = 0.$

Now, we take note of the other SES we had defined above
$$
0 \to K' \to P' \xrightarrow{\varphi'} M \to 0
$$
and since it is exact, we have that $\operatorname{Im}(\psi') = \operatorname{ker}(\varphi')$ so that for each $p' \in P'$ such that $\varphi'(p') = 0$ there exists an $k' \in K'$ so that $\psi'(k') = p'$. And since $\psi'$ is injective, we have that if $\psi'(k'_1) = \psi'(k'_2) \implies k_1' = k_2'$.

Hence we have (I believe) an isomorphism $K' \cong \operatorname{ker}(\pi)$ due to the fact that we earlier concluded that $\operatorname{ker}(\pi)$ is exactly elements $p' \in P'$ such that $\varphi'(p') = 0$.

We see that it follows that $$X \cong \operatorname{ker}(\pi) \oplus P \cong K' \oplus P \underbrace{\cong}_{\text{canonical isomorphism}} P \oplus K'.$$

Now, I assume the second case is done similarly.

Is this correct? If not, what is wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $$X \cong P’ \oplus K$$ @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: .@MarianoSuárez-Álvarez do you agree? The idea is to show that $$X \cong P' \oplus K$$ and $$X \cong P \oplus K'$$ so that $$X \cong P' \oplus K \cong P \oplus K'.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your claims are, indeed, all true. They follow from more general properties of exact sequences and fibre products.

First, whenever you have surjection $g\colon B\twoheadrightarrow C$, you can complete this to an short exact sequence
$$
0 \to A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{g} C\to 0
$$
by defining $A=\ker(g)$ and letting $f$ be the canonical inclusion $\ker(g)\hookrightarrow B$.

Second, if you form the fibre product $X$ of a surjection $P\to M$ with *any* map $P'\to M$, the resulting map $X\to P'$ is always surjective. Indeed, if we define $x$ explicitly to be
$$
X=\{(p,p')\in P\times P'\,|\,\varphi(p)=\varphi'(p')\}
$$
then $X\to P$ and $X\to P'$ are just the restrictions of the coordinate projections. In particular, if $p'\in P'$ we can let $m=\varphi'(p')$ and choose a $\varphi$-preimage $p\in P$. Then $(p,p')\in X$ since $\varphi(p)=m=\varphi'(p')$ by construction. As along $X\to P'$, $(p,p')$ is mapped to $p'$, this shows surjectivity.

Third, since we just saw how the map $\pi\colon X\to P$ is explicitly constructed, its kernel is naturally isomorphic to $K'$. The argument you gave here is perfectly fine.

---

The second and third point actually generalise beyond the explicit realisation of the fibre product: they follow from the definition of the fibre product as a *universal object*. If you do not know too much about this kind of stuff, do not worry. It is not important for this particular problem.

---

One can however avoid (the explicit usage) of fibre products.

By the lifting property of projective moduels, we can complete the given diagram as:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> K @>{\psi}>> P @>{\varphi}>> M @>>> 0
\\
{} @V{\beta}VV @V{\alpha}VV @V{1_M}VV
\\
0 @>>> K'@>>{\psi'}> P' @>>{\varphi'}> M @>>> 0
\end{CD}
This uses *only* projectivity of $P$. Now I claim that there is a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to K \to K'\oplus P \to P' \to 0
$$
where we define $K\to K'\oplus P$ and $K'\oplus P\to P'$ naturally from the abundance of given maps (to not spoil the fun, I will this part to you; let me know if you need any help). Now using *only* the projectivity of $P'$, we deduce that the above sequence is split-exact and therefore
$$
K'\oplus P\cong K\oplus P'\,.
$$
I said above that we avoid the *explicit* usage of fibre products; indeed, a commuting square as above together with the (appropriate) short exact sequence below is actually equivalent to be a fibre product (even, the fibre product you considered).